# Laravel + Pusher Expected parameter 2 to be an array, string given in live chat

Tags: php, laravel, pusher, laravel-echo

I've been following this [blog post](https://pusher.com/tutorials/chat-laravel/#broadcasting-message-sent-event) by pusher in their official site for building basic chat app with laravel + pusher.

I've followed every step thoroughly according to the blog, I'd search here and there as some details were not mentioned there.

I can send the message between users (save in DB table) but not updating in realtime in users end.

The below is the error message I get when I press send message button:
[image]

Here are the snippets from my code file that I have written.

**Events/MessageSent.php**

```
use App\User;
use App\Message;
class MessageSent implements ShouldBroadcast
{
  use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;
  public $user;
  public $message;

 public function __construct(User $user, Message $message)
 {
    $this->message = $message;
    $this->user = $user;
 }

 public function broadcastOn()
 {
    return new PrivateChannel('chat');
 }
}
```

**Broutes/channels.php**

```
Broadcast::channel('chat', function ($user) {
  return Auth::check();
});
```

**web.php**

```
Auth::routes();
Route::get('/', 'ChatsController@index');
Route::get('messages', 'ChatsController@fetchMessages');
Route::post('messages', 'ChatsController@sendMessage');
```

**ChatsController.php**

```
use App\Events\MessageSent;
use App\Message;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Auth;
class ChatsController extends Controller
{
  public function __construct()
  {
    $this->middleware('auth');
  }

  public function index()
  {
    return view('chat');
  }

  public function fetchMessages()
  {
    return Message::with('user')->get();
  }

  public function sendMessage(Request $request)
  {
    $user = Auth::user();

    $message = $user->messages()->create([
        'message' => $request->message,
    ]);

    broadcast(new MessageSent($user, $message))->toOthers();
    
    return ['status' => 'Message Sent!'];
  }
}
```

I'm using laravel version 5.5, pusher 6.1.

The blog post is written for laravel 5.4 and pusher 2.6.

Is version difference causing this issue ?
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to downgrade the pusher version.

`composer require pusher/pusher-php-server ^4.1`

will still be looking for the appropriate answer for latest version.